# Trying to Create a bucket getting object is missing response

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge

Tried to talk to the api with the following Request:

```
POST /oss/v2/buckets/ HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
Authorization: "Bearer sOla4eICLR6IBcx0892MvPjJ***"
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1018dee7-22f1-d20b-4d11-32c4fd41d525

{
  "bucketKey":"energymetrics.bucket1",
  "policyKey":"transient"
}
```

Response:

```
{{
  "developerMessage": "Object is missing",
  "userMessage": "",
  "errorCode": "",
  "more info": "http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/"
}}
```

Tried in both PostMan and C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you're using the URL without the trailing slash

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets
```

Comment: Doh, that's it! Thanks!