# Is bucket creation possible at this time?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Following several blogs, docs, and tutorials I have registered an app, fetched a token for data:read, write, bucket:read, create, but when attempting to create a bucket I get an BadRequest error stating "Object is missing".

```
{
  "developerMessage":"Object is missing",
  "userMessage":"",
  "errorCode":"",
  "more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/"
}
```

I submit `{"bucketKey":"lower case guid", "policyKey":"transient"}`

Kind regards

Comment: fyi I added an object for permissions and that doesn't change the response at all.
{"bucketKey":"lower case guid", "policyKey":"transient", "allow":[{"authId":"my app key", "access":"full"}]}

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40752307/4838205

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Augusto.

We did indeed have a trailing "/" at the end of the url https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets and that's what broke it. took it away and it works as expected now.

Cheers,
Gregor